# RestAssured responseOptions is NULL

Tags: java, build.gradle, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I have below method to call the rest endpoint via SerenityBDD

```
public class RequestSpecs {
...
...
public static Response request(Function<RequestSpecification, Response> method, RequestSpecification spec) {
    RequestSpecification call = ((RequestSpecification)SerenityRest.rest().spec(spec).log().all()).when();
    return (Response)((ValidatableResponse)((ValidatableResponse)((Response)method.apply(call)).then()).log().all()).extract().response();    //>>> ****** RequestSpecs.java:32 **********
}
```

I get follwing error when run test using gradle runner locally.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions.statusLine()" because "responseOptions" is null
        at io.restassured.internal.print.ResponsePrinter.print(ResponsePrinter.java:49)
        at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.logResponse(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:400)
        at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.logResponse(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:396)
        at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.logResponse(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:392)
        at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.all(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:348)
        at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.super$2$all(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:164)
        at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.all(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy:100)
        at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.all(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
        at com.abc.apiautomation.specs.RequestSpecs.request(RequestSpecs.java:32)
```

However if the application start-up via IntelliJ IDE and run SerenityBDD tests wont have any issues.

Versions:

```
gradle-7.4.2

serenityCucumber        : "2.6.0",
serenityReports         : "3.1.0",
cucumberCore            : "6.10.4",
restAssured             : "2.6.0",
vintage                 : "5.8.1",
```

Comment: don't see serenity bdd code path here.

Comment: Weird thing happened here. The root cause seems like due to skipping all the feature files from top level (e.g. `@skip Feature: xxxxx`)and leave ONLY one scenario unskipped in one feature file (did this just for testing). Once removed all feature level `@skip` tags it worked. Not sure the reason behind still